# evaluating number which is more than min and less than max

Tags: ms-access

I am doing this in query design view in MS Access, i need to show record which have charge weight more than (cboOperator2 (textbox in Edit Search Form) = >) min_New(user entered text box in Edit Search Form) and less than (cboOperator2 (textbox in Edit Search Form) = <) max_New (user enter text box in Edit Search Form). Following seems not working and it is not giving error either. Here is the screenshot and expression I am trying with.

[image: searchq (query design view) screenshot]

```
IIf(
    [Forms]![Edit Search Form]![cboOperator2] Is Null Or
    [Forms]![Edit Search Form]![min_NEW] Is Null Or
    [Forms]![Edit Search Form]![max_NEW] Is Null Or
    [Forms]![Edit Search Form]![cboOperator3] Is Null,

    True,

    IIf(
        [Charge_Weight] Is Null,

        Null,

        Eval(
            [Charge_Weight] &
            [Forms]![Edit Search Form]![cboOperator2] &
            [Forms]![Edit Search Form]![min_New] &
            [Charge_Weight] &
            [Forms]![Edit Search Form]![cboOperator3] &
            [Forms]![Edit Search Form]![max_New]
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a query, which returns

```
[Charge_Weight] &
[Forms]![Edit Search Form]![cboOperator2] &
[Forms]![Edit Search Form]![min_New] &
[Charge_Weight] &
[Forms]![Edit Search Form]![cboOperator3] &
[Forms]![Edit Search Form]![max_New]
```

in order to see which expression is evaluated in `Eval`.

---

Shouldn't there be an `AND` somewhere?

```
[Charge_Weight] &
[Forms]![Edit Search Form]![cboOperator2] &
[Forms]![Edit Search Form]![min_New] &
" AND " &
[Charge_Weight] &
[Forms]![Edit Search Form]![cboOperator3] &
[Forms]![Edit Search Form]![max_New]
```

yielding an expression like

```
20 > 10 AND 20 < 100
```